# How to append value from more than 1 dropdowns into a single formcontrol in a reactive form?

Tags: angular8, angular-reactive-forms, form-control

I have a loop which contains dropdown in a form. I want the values entered in all the dropdowns to be appended in a single formcontrol in reactive form. But it is putting only last dropdown value .
How  to achieve this?

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let prod of products;" >
     <div class="col-4 cols">
          <div class="">{{prod.name}}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
         <div class="">
            <ng-select class="required" [items]="prod.companies" bindLabel="name" placeholder="Select company" [searchable]="false" formControlName="companies">
                              <ng-option [value]=""></ng-option>
             </ng-select>
          </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

This is a part of code inside  tag. In this form, for multiple products from a list which will come from backend, a dropdown will be their containing companies with respect to product.The companies  selected for multiple products should go into a single formcontrol . But only the value chosen last from any of the dropdown is getting assigned to the comapnies formcontrol instead of an array of companies selected from multiple products.

the form in component.ts is :

```
 setform(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      id: [''],
      name: [''],
      companies: [null]
    });
  }
```

Comment: Please add source code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi @Mridul, I have edited my question. Can you  help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

add [multiple]="true" in ng-select and get multiple select value.
For example see this link:- https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select

Comment: Hi vivek, I have to bind values from different dropdowns into a single form control. And all the dropdowns must be single select.